# Django SuperUser to use standard User model and have app users use CustomUser model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin, django-custom-user

I have an app where I won't be needing email/username or passwords for User authentication.
However, I want my superuser to still use the username and password authentication.

Basically, how do I force superusers to use the built-in Django User model?
And other app users use my Custom User model?

I feel like there may not be a way since Django only allows you to pick one model in the settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'users.CustomUser'
```

Comment: Simplest would probably be just to keep single model with custom authentication backend https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend

Comment: I'm honestly not sure if I'm understanding you correctly. You want to have a superuser login using the built in userform on django??

Comment: @AaronCloud I have a custom User model. this custom user model does not have a username/password setup (Etherum based Dapp login), but I want my superuser to have a username/password